# Issue setting up Cascading drop downs in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cascadingdropdown, view-helpers

I've been trying to implement the code in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310436/cascading-dropdown-lists-mvc3)

Issues are:-

1. Setting up or creation of helper
2. integrating helper onto view to perform CascadingDropDropListFor

At 1st I tried making a new class for the helper then I instead moved the code into my existing model for the page but found if I did that it solved the issue 2 just to say I couldn't nest the public static class into my public class StudentViewModel.

To solve issue 1 I tried inputing as many "Using" as needed to get all the code to work and then I found that Web.Mvc.Html was meant to resolve it but didn't and caused another error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
```

I did find that

```
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
```

Solved the *Html*.SelectExtension issue which you can see the error below

> The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

But caused

> 'SelectListItem' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' and
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem'

Below you can see the helper code which was suggested but I think I must be doing something wrong at some stage to keep causing these different errors to pop up.

```
            public static class MvcHtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString CascadingDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
            string optionLabel,
            IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes,
            string parentControlName,
            string childListUrl
            )
        {
            var memberName = GetMemberInfo(expression).Member.Name;
            MvcHtmlString returnHtml = Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(htmlHelper, expression, selectList, optionLabel, htmlAttributes);
            var returnString = MvcHtmlString.Create(returnHtml.ToString() +
                @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
                    $(document).ready(function () { 
                        $(""#<<parentControlName>>"").change(function () {                                  
                            var postData = { <<parentControlName>>: $(""#<<parentControlName>>"").val() };                                 
                            $.post('<<childListUrl>>', postData, function (data) {                                     
                                var options = """";                                     
                                $.each(data, function (index) {                                         
                                    options += ""<option value='"" + data[index].Id + ""'>"" + data[index].Name + ""</option>"";                                     
                                });                                     
                                $(""#<<memberName>>"").html(options);                                 
                            })                                 
                            .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(jqXHR.responseText); });                             
                        });                         
                    });                      
                </script>"
                .Replace("<<parentControlName>>", parentControlName)
                .Replace("<<childListUrl>>", childListUrl)
                .Replace("<<memberName>>", memberName));
            return returnString;
        }
        private static MemberExpression GetMemberInfo(Expression method)
        {
            LambdaExpression lambda = method as LambdaExpression;
            if (lambda == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
            MemberExpression memberExpr = null;
            if (lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
            {
                memberExpr = ((UnaryExpression)lambda.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
            }
            else if (lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
            {
                memberExpr = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
            }
            if (memberExpr == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("method");
            return memberExpr;
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise if anybody knowns of a much simpler way of implementing cascading dropdown lists in mvc3 I'll try that out instead but I've already been looking at a bunch of other search results for it and this had been the one I had figured easiest to implement.

Anyway any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the AjaxDropdown from http://awesome.codeplex.com and you won't need to write javascript anymore

Comment: I looked at that but the issue there is with finding out exactly what I would need from the whole project which includes a lot, I'll give it another look now but if there are any key things you think I should be looking for that need to be copied directly across like specific jscript or controller code then anything will help, thanks.

Comment: Ok I finally got it to work last night but it turns out that it doesn't like complex object referencing so I couldn't refer to an id for a table record in the viewmodel so just had to make an int and use that as the object then sort the connection out in the controller.  Plus I didn't like that it refused to accept edmx's and required the use of dbml's for linq to sql.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(..);
```

instead of

```
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
```